# Github REST api GET Returns not found

Tags: rest, github

I'm trying to use GitHub REST api to get files from public repositories but I get a message not found, although it exists.

This is the link of the file: https://github.com/COVID19Tracking/covid-tracking-data/blob/master/data/counties.csv

I changed it as specified in Github REST specification: https://api.github.com/repos/COVID19Tracking/covid-tracking-data/blob/master/data/counties.csv

I'm using Postman, and I get the following:

[image]

So What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) says:

> ```
> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
> ```

You said:

> ```
> GET /repos/COVID19Tracking/covid-tracking-data/blob/master/data/counties.csv
> ```

So:

- `/repos/` check
- `:owner` check
- `:repo` check
- `/contents/` Nope. You put `/blob/master/` there instead
- `:path` check

The URL is https://api.github.com/repos/COVID19Tracking/covid-tracking-data/contents/data/counties.csv